# ¿Qué palabra o término en español se puede utilizar para la palabra en inglés 'disclaimer'?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Según un diccionario en inglés, 'disclaimer' es "una sentencia que niega algo, especialmente responsabilidad". ¿Qué palabra o término en español se puede utilizar en su lugar?